# Exposing inner classes when obfuscating with ProGuard

Tags: java, ant, proguard

I'm obfuscating a library with ProGuard using the Ant task.

I'm keeping particular class names and their method names when they have a particular annotation (@ApiAll) and I'm requesting that the InnerClasses attribute be kept:

```
  <keepattribute name="InnerClasses" />
  <keep annotation="com.example.ApiAll"/>
  <keepclassmembers annotation="com.example.ApiAll">
     <constructor access="public protected"/>
     <field access="public  protected"/>
     <method access="public  protected"/>
     <constructor access="protected"/>
    </keepclassmembers>
```

If I check the mapping output file I can see that my inner class that has the annotation and it's members are keeping their names unobfuscated.  However when I look in the generated jar file I can't find the class.

Am I missing something?  Why is the mapping telling me it's keeping this class when it's not?

Answer (score 22):

You need to specify that you want to keep the inner class using the proper notation.
In the proguard parlance, that means `-keep class my.outer.Class$MyInnerClass`. The key here is using the dollar-sign (`$`) as the separator between inner and outer class.

To do this, you also have to specify `-keepattributes InnerClasses`, so that the name `MyInnerClass` doesn't get obfuscated. These two settings together should allow your inner classes to be kept intact.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the same problem with yGuard

Answer (score 1):

The option `keepclassmembers` only preserves the specified class members (and their names).

You probably want the more common option `keep`, which preserves the specified classes *and* class members (and their names).

Cfr. [ProGuard manual > Usage > Overview of Keep Options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoverview)