# Using ProGuard to obfuscate code

Tags: java, applet, obfuscation, proguard

I chose ProGuard and here's the options I configured it with:

**Shrinking**

*Options:*

- Shrink

*Keep:*

- Applications
- Applets

*Also keep:*

- Enumerations
- Database drivers
- Swing UI L&F

**Obfuscation**

*Options:*

- Obfuscate (duh! :P)
- Overload aggressively
- Use unique class member names
- Use mixed-casee class names
- Flatten package hierarchy
- Repackage classes

*Keep names:*

- native method names
- .class method names

**Optimization**

*Options:*

- Optimize
- Merge interfaces aggressively

*Remove:*

- [All boxes checked]

**Information**

*Preverifiaction and targeting:*

- Preverify

*Consistency and correctness:*

- Note potential mistakes in the configuration
- Warn about possibly errornous input
- Skip non-public library class members

and when I take the jar and put it as:

I get this applet error upon launch:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: b
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: b
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: b
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: open HTTP connection failed:http://mystikrpg.com/b.class
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.getBytes(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        ... 17 more
    Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: b
```

Here is what is INSIDE the jar file BEFORE the obfuscation `clientOffline.jar`:

```
line_tile/
META-INF/
```

and here is what that jar file is AFTER the obfuscation to `newOne.jar`:

```
line_tile/
META-INF/
weapon/
me.gif
a.class
b.class
```

I hope this is good enough to help me solve this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that b.class is generated from the GamePanel inner class. So there can be a problem with inner classes. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165658/exposing-inner-classes-when-obfuscating-with-proguard) at Stackoverflow Tom mentioned that he could not obfuscate inner classes correctly. The suggestion there also applies here: try to obfuscate with `verbose=true` (or with java -jar proguard.jar @myconfig.pro -verbose).

I would also suggest to use -keepnames option (see [manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/sections.html)) for GamePanel and/or tileOffline since it will leave these classes unchanged by the obfuscation (at least for finding the root cause of the problem).

A side note is try to use [CamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) class names when programming in Java.

Comment: Uhm, I do have keep names option checked. But it would be `java -jar proguard.jar @myconfig.pro -verbose -keepnames` right?

Comment: "-keepnames class_specification" is the correct format where class specification can be "class tileOffline" in this cases